# Snap Package doesn't integrate with GTK, why?

Tags: gtk, snap

I recently downloaded Libreoffice in Snap package format.
However it doesn't integrate very well or at all into to the system GTK settings.

Is there a way to forcible integrate snap packages?

Comment: How's it looking now? [System theme integration is still to-do](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/use-the-system-gtk-theme/496), however...